# Why won't the edit method in my controller redirect the url to the update method?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, controller

Right now I am trying make a few functions in the controller class that is supposed to update a blog post. In the controller superclass, there is a function that makes it so functions can be executed by the name of the method and parameters put in the url. When I direct my view to the edit function the edit function works fine. However when the set method changes the task array to update, its supposed to redirect the url to execute the update function. However it is not doing that. I have tried adding parameters in the update function, I have tried removing all parameters in the update function. I have even tried editing the view so that the it submits again as the task array is set to update. What exactly am I supposed to do to make the update function call upon declaring the task set method. I apologize if my wording sounds confusing but it's kind of hard to explain the problem.

Here is the code for the Controller super-class

```
 <?php

        class Controller {

        public $load;
            public $data = array();


        function __construct($view, $method = null, $parameters = null){
                    //instantiate the load class
                    $this->load = new Load();
                    new Model();
                    //run any task methods
                    if($method){
                        $this->runTask($method, $parameters);
                    }else{
                        $this->defaultTask();
                    }
                    //render the view
                    $this->load->view($view.'.php', $this->data);
        }

        /*
        *The runTask() method is our way of grabbing the method from the URI string and parsing the parameters
        */
        public function runTask($method, $parameters = null){

            if($method && method_exists($this, $method)) {

                        //the call_user_func_array expects an array so we create a null array if parameters is empty
                        if(!is_array($parameters)){
                            $parameters = array();
                        }

              call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters); 

            }

        }

        /*
        *The defaultTask() method is the one run if no task method is run. Here as a placeholder for child classes.
        */
        public function defaultTask(){

        }


        /*
        *The set() method allows us to more easily set the view variables
        */
        public function set($key, $value){

            $this->data[$key] = $value;

        }



    }
```

Here is the controller's subclass where the edit and update functions are

```
<?php

    class AddPostController extends Controller{

        public $postObject;

        public function defaultTask(){

            $this->postObject = new Post();
            $this->set('task', 'add');


        }

        public function add(){

                $this->postObject = new Post();

                $data = array('title'=>$_POST['post_title'],'content'=>$_POST['post_content'],
                               'categoryID'=>$_POST['categoryID'],'date'=>$_POST['date']);


                $result = $this->postObject->addPost($data);

                $this->set('message', $result);


        }

        public function edit($pID){

                $this->postObject = new Post();

                $post = $this->postObject->getPost($pID);


                $this->set('pID', $post['pID']);
                $this->set('date', $post['date']);
                $this->set('categoryID', $post['categoryID']);
                $this->set('title', $post['title']);
                $this->set('content', $post['content']);
                $this->set('task', 'update'); //This should redirect to update  method


        }
        public function update() {
             echo 'controller update';
             echo sizeof($data);
             echo sizeof($this->data);
            //$this->postObject->update($data);

        }


    }
```

Here is the add or edit post view

```
<?php include('elements/admin_header.php');?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
   <h1> the Add Post View </h1>
  </div>
  <?php if($message){?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <?php echo $message?>
    </div>
  <?php }?>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">

       <form method="post" action="" name="edit">
            <label>Edit Post #</label>
             <select name="pID" onchange="edit.submit();">
             <option value="Post">Post</option>
            <?php 
                 if(is_numeric($_POST['pID']) ==false){

                }else{
                echo '<option selected value='.$_POST['pID'].'>'.$_POST['pID'].'</option>';
                     $task='edit/'.$_POST['pID'];
                }

                /*if(is_numeric($_POST['pID'])==false){
                    $update=false;
                }else{
                 echo '<option selected="selected" value='.$_POST['pID'].'>'.$_POST['pID'].'</option>';
                   $update=true;
                }*/
                  //This is to populate post number select.
                  $post = new Post();
                  $maxPost=sizeof($post->getAllPosts());
                  for($postNum=1; $postNum<=$maxPost; $postNum++){
                     echo '<option value='.$postNum.'>'.$postNum.'</option>';
                  }

            ?>
            </select>
        </form>
        <form action="<?php echo BASE_URL?>addpost/<?php echo $task?>" method="post" onsubmit="editor.post()">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="span6" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $title?>">
                <label>Content</label>
          <textarea id="tinyeditor" name="post_content" style="width:556px;height: 200px"><?php echo $content?></textarea>
                <br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="pID" value="<?php echo $pID?>"/>
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="date"  />
          <label>Category ID</label>
          <input type="number" name="categoryID"  /> <br />
          <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
        </form>


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('elements/admin_footer.php');?>
```

Comment: When you use the set method to set the task to "update", the set method just stores the information in array and does not do anything else. how is the controller supposed to know that the task has changed and execute it. May be you need to call runTask to process it or am I missing something?

Comment: The set task is supposed to change the form action link in the view to update and then redirect it. At least that's how I think it supposed to work

Comment: I have added an answer with extra explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing some code, which might guide you in the right direction...

```
public function set($key, $value){
    // this following line only updates data and that's it
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
    // you need to call run task method, so that the new task will be executed    
    if($key == "task") {   
    $this->runTask($value, $parameters);
    }
}
```

you might need to change signature of set method to pass parameters etc, but that's upto you how to handle it.

//Edit: If the key is "task" then execute the runTask method

Answer (score 0):

Usually (from what I see on different Frameworks) this code should not be in the Base controller.

usually there's a router class that takes the URI and defines (according to some naming convention or a list of regex paths) what controller and what action should be called.

Then it call another class, usually called a "Dispatch", that create the instance of the controller and calls the action method passing the parameters needed.

This might be a cleaner way to do it.. and It will help you debugging

Hope this helps